# AngularJs how to change height depending on amount of values in the table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, scroll

I got a pretty simple AngularJS application with couple tables on the page.
I wanted to implement scroll there so I used simple css code like:

```
tbody {
 overflow: auto;
}
```

with defined height for each table. After that I tried [https://github.com/cornflourblue/angu-fixed-header-table](http://angu-fixed-header-table) implementation but it almost looks the same (that's why I preferred simplest solution).

So, **the problem is** - scroll works great if I have a lot of values in my table, but while I got only one row - I got a lot of empty space cause the height fixed with one value.
Pure table with angularjs works perfectly and changes the height based on amount of values but there is no scroll.

What is the best way to implement scrolling for table if I would like to avoid white space, but I also would like to see scroll after 15 values in the table?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try `min-height` and `max-height` in css

```
tbody {
    min-height = 5em; /**You might also consider the extra space for padding**/
    max-height = 15em;
}
```

This will pad your tbody's height to at least 5em and shall show a scroll bar once it hits 15em.

Comment: It looks like angular ignores <tbody style="min-height: 5em; max-height: 10em; overflow: auto"> style
[Screenshot 2][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzdyn.png

Comment: i checked one of my old projects, i used div all the way and make it look like an old-school table via css.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ng-style, with the help of ng-style css can be change according to expression or any other logic.

Comment: Hm, I found some examples: `<div id="wrapper" ng-style="{height: '{{hgt}}px'}">
  <h4 class="headerTitle">title</h4>
</div>` so I can change heith of table, and could try to enable scroll while I got 20 rows. Will try, thanks.